# Auto increment without mouse

Tags: excel

I'm write in a cell 1, then put the mouse over the black square at the bottom-right corner of that cell, right click and drag.

Principal question - I do not want to use a mouse. And look for script or keyboard hotkeys to got similar numbers

1   3

3   6

5   9

from keyword selected

1   3

3   6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the following macros in my Personal Macro Workbook and assigned a keyboard shortcut.

```
Sub FillSeries()

    Dim lFirstBlank As Long

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Or Selection.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            lFirstBlank = GetFirstBlank(Selection)
            If lFirstBlank = 0 Then
                SelectAdjacentCol
                lFirstBlank = GetFirstBlank(Selection)
            End If
            If lFirstBlank > 1 Then
                If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
                    Selection.Cells(1).Resize(lFirstBlank - 1).AutoFill _
                        Selection, xlFillSeries
                ElseIf Selection.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                    Selection.Cells(1).Resize(, lFirstBlank - 1).AutoFill _
                        Selection, xlFillSeries
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFirstBlank(rRng As Range) As Long

    Dim i As Long

    i = 0

    For i = 1 To rRng.Cells.Count
        If IsEmpty(rRng.Cells(i)) Then
            GetFirstBlank = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function

Sub SelectAdjacentCol()

    Dim rAdjacent As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If Selection.Column > 1 Then
            If Not IsEmpty(Selection.Offset(0, -1).Value) Then
                With Selection.Offset(0, -1)
                    Set rAdjacent = .Parent.Range(.Cells(1), .End(xlDown))
                End With

                Selection.Resize(rAdjacent.Cells.Count).Select
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

See also http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2008/07/17/fillseries-keyboard-shortcut/

**Update**

If you only want to fill columns and you want to fill all the columns in a selection, then the below code should do what you want. It also looks at the NumberFormat of the *last* cell in the column and changes the NumberFormat for filled cells back to that. Picking the last cell is a little arbitrary, but it is what it is.

```
Sub FillSeriesForAllColumns()

    Dim lFirstBlank As Long
    Dim rCol As Range
    Dim sOldNumberFormat As String

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        For Each rCol In Selection.Columns
            sOldNumberFormat = Selection.Cells(Selection.Cells.Count).NumberFormat
            lFirstBlank = GetFirstBlank(rCol)
            If lFirstBlank = 0 Then
                SelectAdjacentCol
                lFirstBlank = GetFirstBlank(rCol)
            End If
            If lFirstBlank > 1 Then
                rCol.Cells(1).Resize(lFirstBlank - 1).AutoFill _
                    rCol, xlFillSeries
            End If

            rCol.Offset(lFirstBlank - 1, 0).Resize(rCol.Row - (lFirstBlank - 1)).NumberFormat = sOldNumberFormat

        Next rCol
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: how to do this with two columns, how to make only for number values not format

Comment: This will fill series down a column or across a row, so it has to be limited to either one column or row. If you only want to fill columns, then you can change it to loop through the columns. As far as format, I think your stuck. Excel's FillSeries does not have an option to only fill values. If you only want values you'd have to write your own FillSeries algorithm. Or I guess you could set the formatting to General when you're done.

Comment: i'm need any work algoritm to make square 2rows*2col to 3rows*2col. For a hower learn vba to do that

Comment: Thenks for your support. Need a little debug. 
from
0.4936 -0.0696
0.4926 -0.0661
must be
0.4936 -0.0696
0.4926 -0.0661
0.4916 -0.0626

instead of this script makes
from
0.4936 -0.0696
0.4926 -0.0661
script makkes
0.4936 -0.0696
1.4936 0.9304
2.4936 1.9304

Comment: it works correctly, I forgot to change the rest part of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the **arrow** keys select the column section including the header cell:

[image]

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and touch **hfis** sequentially.  Then release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and touch the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

..after:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand last steps, what mean hfis?

Comment: It means first touch **h** then touch **f** then touch **i** then touch **s** all while holding douwn the **ALT** key.

Comment: ok thanks case i'm got a lot of data to repeat this fot thousand times. Now i use script answered upward and I am now trying to rewrite it to make possibility to use macros for selected square instead line or single value

Comment: @Artem.Borysov I agree with you.  I like the macro also.

Comment: found like to autofill only numbers - 'xlFillSeries' replace to 'xlFillValues' in text upper. yet i don't find solution for ability to few columns launch